# How to process a GCS filepattern, full file at a time?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I need to process a (GCS) bucket of files, where each file is compressed and contains a single multi-line JSON record. Also, the name of the file being processed is significant and I need to know it within my transform.

Starting with examples in the docs, TextIO looks pretty close, but it looks like its designed to process each file line-by-line and does not allow me to read the entire file at once. Also, I don't see any way to get the filename that's being processed?

```
PCollectionTuple results = p.apply(TextIO.Read
    .from("gs://bucket/a/*.gz")
    .withCompressionType(TextIO.CompressionType.GZIP)
    .withCoder(MyJsonCoder.of()))
```

Looks like I need to write a custom IO reader, or some such? Any tips for best place to start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that right now none of the existing classes do exactly what you want. There are 2 reasonable approaches:

- Match the filepattern yourself (using [IOChannelUtils](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/IOChannelFactory.java) and [IOChannelFactory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/IOChannelUtils.java)) and wrap the resulting files into a `PCollection<String>` where the String will be a filename, using `Create.of(filenames)`. Then apply a `ParDo` with a function which reads the given filename.
- Write your own subclass of [Source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/Source.java) (there's also FileBasedSource, but it's not quite right for your use case). It would be configured by the filepattern, and `splitIntoBundles` would match the filepattern and expand into individual sources each corresponding to one file.

I would recommend the first approach because it seems like less code and your use case does not require the full power of `Source`.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using GcsIOChannelFactory to perform the matching, worked like a charm.